# How to get rid of empty spaces at the end of the page on converting HTML to PDF using page-break-after

Tags: html, css, pdf, printing, html-to-pdf

I want the page height to be same as the content of the element, I am always getting pages with same height even if the content is single line. 
[See the image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mmBkC.png)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you take a screenshot shot and then convert to pdf